# Macro to revert changes since save

Tags: vba, excel

I found an old script online to close the document without saving the changes, then re-open the document:

```
Sub RevertFile()
  wkname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
  ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=False
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=wkname
End Sub
```

I want this since you can't "undo" changes caused by running a macro. However, it does not seem to work in MS Office v1609. Firstly, the document does not re-open after it is closed. Secondly, the modifications *are* saved when I want them not to be. How can I rewrite this script to get it to work? Thanks.

[edit]

Here is the other sub-routine I am using.

```
Sub FixPlatforms()
'PURPOSE: Find & Replace a list of text/values throughout entire workbook
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim platList As Variant
Dim x As Long

platList = Array _
( _
    "PS4", "PlayStation 4", _
    "PS3", "PlayStation 3", _
    "PS2", "PlayStation 2", _
    "PSV", "PlayStation Vita", _
    "PSP", "PlayStation Portable", _
    "WIN", "Microsoft Windows", _
    "SNES", "Super Nintendo Entertainment System" _
)


'Loop through each item in Array lists
  For x = 1 To UBound(platList) Step 2
    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=platList(x), Replacement:=platList(x - 1), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next sht

  Next x

End Sub
```

Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Does your sub procedure save the workbook? There is no reason for that code to save changes.

Comment: I updated my question with the other routine.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong although I would reverse the order of the loops and loop through the worksheets on the outside and the array on the inside (or use an array of worksheets to globally search & replace).

Comment: Isn't your platList zero-based? Should it be `For x = LBound(platList) To UBound(platList) Step 2` just to be sure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have to close the workbook in any event. Attempting to open a workbook that is already open produces the following.

[image]

Adding `application.displayalerts = false` should be sufficient to avoid that confirmation.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RevertFile()
    Dim wkname As String
    wkname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=wkname
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Nothing visible happened at all. No error or anything. It is as though the macro wasn't running at all, but it definitely is because I have set breakpoints. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: Not working for me either.. On Mac if I try to open a workbook that's already open, it doesn't alert me, it just brings the open workbook to the front. This is exactly what this VBA Sub is doing—merely focusing on the workbook that's already open.