# How can I use VBA to revert ThisWorkbook to a previously saved state?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like a macro to undo ALL changes since the workbook was last opened/saved.

I thought this would be as easy as re-opening the workbook, similar to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44244262/1473412

However, when I use:

```
Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
```

Literally NOTHING happens. No alert, no error, no change. It is as though the command is just ignored. Has this behaviour changed in recent versions of Excel?

What is the easiest way to revert a workbook to its previously saved state in the latest version of excel (2016)?

Thanks,

Comment: What Excel version? This works fine on Excel 2013. One thing you might want to check are the auto-save and auto-recover options.

Comment: Please include the whole relevant code part or a [mcve].

Comment: `Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.FullName)` You need to close the workbook without saving and then reopen it....

Comment: @Comintern 2016

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I have. Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.FullName) is all the code you need. Put that in a blank workbook and run it. Nothing happens.

Comment: @SiddharthRout While you are right this not possible if the code is running in `ThisWorkbook` ^^ Because closing kills the code execution immediately.

Comment: @SiddharthRout How would I do that exactly? If the code to re-open the workbook is in the workbook which has just been closed, is that going to work?

Comment: Why the down vote? And why the flag to close?

Comment: No idea. I did not do it. Whoever voted it must have done it by mistake I guess... Anyways I have posted an answer. you may have to refresh the page to see it.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ The statement "this not possible if the code is running in ThisWorkbook" is not correct - the OP's code does exactly what is described in Excel 2013 - execution continues normally, as does the code in the linked question. Closing the workbook has no effect on code running in that workbook unless execution is stopped (or it tries to use the workbook object).

Comment: @Comintern Have you actually tried it? Code which comes after the workbook is closed does not run. Code which comes after `Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.FullName)`, will run, but only because that line has no effect and the workbook is never closed. If you try to run code after changing the file access, as per @Pᴇʜ answer, it does not run.

Comment: @Comintern In Excel 2016 it does nothing. It does not reload the file. Also closing a workbook **always** breaks code execution.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Did you try it? Gravitate - Yes. I tried both your code and the linked code. It worked fine in Excel 2013. See the very first comment.

Comment: @Comintern We aren't talking about Excel 2013. We are talking about 2016. Although, `Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.FullName)` may work in 2013, it does not in 2016.

Comment: I know that. What I'm pointing out is that the statement made in the comment is not *universally* true. If somebody finds this question later and reads the comments, that will be clear now.

Comment: @Comintern Right, I see. Sorry, I miss understood.

Comment: @Comintern But I still find it strange that it works in 2013 but not in 2016 (that means the feature is either broken or removed by purpose). • Can you confirm that any changes made the workbook get indeed reverted and disappear? • Because this code indeed does not break code excecution but also it does not revert any changes.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yep - the changes made to the workbook since the last save get reverted in 2013.  As for why, my best guess is that the *old* behavior was broken and it was fixed. Possibly to address Excel's nasty habit of leaving ghost processes hanging around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic:

Close the Excel file without saving and simply re-open it. But then how do I reopen it from the same file?

1. Create a VBScript from your code
2. Put a Delay of say 3 secs in that and the code to open the Excel file
3. Call the vbscript and close the current file.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim file As String
    file = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DeletemeLater.vbs"

    Sheet1.Range("A2").Value = "Blah Blah" '<~~ This change will not be saved

    '~~> Create a vbscript file
    Open file For Output As #1
    Print #1, "WScript.Sleep 300"
    Print #1, "Set oExcelApp = GetObject(,""Excel.Application"")"
    Print #1, "oExcelApp.Visible=True"
    Print #1, "Set oWB = oExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(" & Chr(34) & ThisWorkbook.FullName & Chr(34) & ")"
    Close #1

    Shell "wscript " & Chr(34) & file & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus

    ThisWorkbook.Close (False)
End Sub
```

And one more thing. Add this in the workbook code area

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill ThisWorkbook.Path & "\DeletemeLater.vbs"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems utterly over engineered to do something which, to me, should be just a case of `Thisworkbook.Revert`. But at first try, it seems to work well. I will do a bit more testing and come back. Do you need the `Print #1, "WScript.Sleep 300"`? Removing it seems to have no adverse affects.

Comment: @Gravitate just that there is no such `ThisWorkbook.Revert` :) So you have to go with one of the workarounds. Workarounds are ugly in many cases, but as long as there is no offical way that's what we have to live with.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ No... I know... already tried that :). I just wish MS could have included it. Wasn't there a manual "Revert" option in the file menu as some point? Or am I thinking of something else?

Comment: @SiddharthRout You might want to change it to `Shell "wscript " & Chr(34) & file & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus` in case of spaces in the path.

Comment: @Gravitate: Utterly Overengineered :D ? This is a very basic workaround for what you want. Also it is good to include a wait period. and hence I would recommend `WScript.Sleep 300`. Also I have edited my post to incorporate your last suggestion. I had missed that...

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes, it is far more complex than it should have to be (a dig at MS, not you). Creating a separate file and then running it through the shell, then deleting it after seems like a lot of work to go through, just to undo a few changes. It does work and I am very grateful to you because I would never have thought of this solution. However, I do feel like there might be situations which could cause it to fall over, just because of the complexity.

Comment: @Gravitate: In that case you have not seen attempts where actual "over engineering" happens to "Undo the changes caused by macro"... A far more complex code is written to store/record every change that happens becuase of a code and all that is reset to original state (step by step)... That is sheer madness :D

Comment: One other way I can think of if creating a copy of the file before your code runs and then when you revert, it copies the content of the duplicate file into the existing sheets and then deletes the duplicate? @Gravitate (This again is more tedious than what i suggested above)

Comment: @SiddharthRout No, I think that is even more complex... particularly because of how complex the workbook in question is. As I say, the solution above works, and I will fix any problems that crop up if/when they happen. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this workaround:

```
Public Sub ReOpenWithoutSave()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly, , False
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadWrite, , True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

- It marks `ThisWorkbook` as already saved (but does not save it).
- It makes `ThisWorkbook` read only and waits 1 second to let it proceed
- It makes `ThisWorkbook` writeable again (which causes a re-open automatically)

Comment: Thank you. That does work in a simple example, however, when I use it in a real world case where macros run on open/close, I get an "Automation Error". Also, any code which is supposed to run AFTER the file is reverted, does not. Presumably because the file executing the code has been closed.

Comment: The issues you describe are no issues specific to the code I posted, you would have them anyway I think. Try to add a `Application.EnableEvents = False` before file access is changed and `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the end. This should disable all the events.

Comment: Yes... except one small thing to take into account... the `Application.EnableEvents = True` code will never run because the workbook will have already closed, terminating the execution. And you can't put it in the workbook open event because that won't run because events are disabled.

Comment: @Gravitate Ah, you are right. Then you will need to use Siddharth Rout's workaround.

Comment: Code copied from another site should be properly atributed, otherwise it is plagiarism.

Comment: On Excel Mac this works (Changes the File Access, which eventually causes the file to reopen), however, when the file opens again the 'Command Ribbon' is completely missing. View > Ribbon is checked and the CMD-OPT-R shortcut toggles it, but the ribbon never shows (Maybe a Bug). **I can however edit the file.